# my wordpress website is down, how to solve this error

Tags: wordpress, parsing

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' in /home/py9de5hew9qy/public_html/wp-content/plugins/fuse-social-floating-sidebar/framework/redux-core/class-redux-core.php on line 460

There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.

how to solve this error

Answer (score 0):

That's obviously caused by the "fuse-social-floating-sidebar" plugin

If you can access the backend, deactivate that plugin, if you can't, erase the  folder of that plugin from the "plugins" folder inside "wp-content" and reinstall the plugin.